# Is npm automatically installed with ASP.NET 5?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've been using ASP.NET 5 RC1 for a while now I know the default web application project template relies on `Bower` which requires `npm` as well. I'm trying to find some definitive information, but am coming up dry. I looked on my machine and I had installed `npm` for Windows using the standalone package much prior to using ASP.NET 5.

I also ran the following from the command line `npm -v` and I got the current `npm` version.

The main question is, does the ASP.NET 5 RC1 install `npm` and `bower`, `VS.NET 2015` install, or is it a prerequisite that a user install `npm` before using ASP.NET 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm` gets installed with visual studio 2015. If you're having trouble to with accessing the visual studio node integration tools you can try install this:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx

Have a look here for information how node integrates with visual studio 2015.

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Npm-Integration

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok yeah according to this link it appears it was an option when VS2015 is originally installed: http://ryanhayes.net/synchronize-node-js-install-version-with-visual-studio-2015/  Looks like though that the `npm` install being updated if installed by VS is subject to it's release updates and one must point to updated versions manually if not wanting to wait. http://jameschambers.com/2015/09/upgrading-npm-in-visual-studio-2015/